# Add json data to existing array using curl

Tags: php, html, json, curl, post

I'm using PHP to send an HTML post request using curl. I want to add more data to an existing JSON array at an URL. If I post a request, does it replace the data or does it add it to the existing array? Currently, I'm writing:

```
// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://www.barn-door.co.uk/wp-json/geodir/v1/farms'); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: '.$authToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
echo $responseData['published'];
```

where $postData is my data in json format.

Thanks :)

Comment: It replaces the current data. Just modify the `$data`-array before you encode it and set it.

Comment: _Note:_ That's not how you send json using cURL. From the manual about CURL_POSTFIELDS: _"This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value."_. You should send the json string in the body instead and make sure that you set the content type to `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge your data before sending

```
// original data
$data = array("firstname" => "Foo");

// your new data
$additionalData = array("surname" => "Bar");

// merge/overwrite
$data = array_merge($data, $additionalData);

//result print_r($data); will output array("firstname" => "Foo", "surname" => "Bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
$arraydata = array("name" => "test","email" =>"test@test.com"); 

$senddata = array_merge($_POST, $arraydata); // $_POST will hold values from form submission

$data_string = json_encode ( $senddata );

$curl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string ); // Insert the data
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
        'Accept: application/json' 
) );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
$result = curl_exec ( $curl );
curl_close ( $curl );
```